# How to sort MongoDB collection based on whether a field exists or not

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my app, I have an endpoint which is supposed to find all users who meet some conditions and then return results as an array. The result is sorted by creation date. Now I need to do more complex sorting.

1) Return users who have uploaded their profile photo first (this is the major condition I have to add)
2) In addition, the results should be sorted by creation date but users with uploaded avatar should be always first (although they've created account later)

This is the code I have:

```
router.get('/users/:page?', ({ params, query }, response) => {
    let { page = 1 } = params;
    page = _.parseInt(page);
    let { limit = 50 } = query;
    limit = _.parseInt(limit);
    const skip = page * limit - limit;

    User.find({ name: { $exists: true }})
        .limit(limit)
        .skip(skip)
        .sort({ created: 1 })
        .exec((error, users) => {
            if (error) {
                return response.status(500).send('users-couldnt-be-found');
            }

            response.status(200).send(users);
        });
});
```

My example json collection:

```
[
    { name: 'Jon without avatar', created: '2020-01-28T22:29:48.603Z' }
    { name: 'Jon with avatar', avatar: '/path/to/file', created: '2020-01-28T22:29:48.603Z' }
]
```

I tried to use `aggregate` and `group` but I don't really understand how it works. I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: Question is not clear, can you add sample documents and the expected output? How will we understand that a user has uploaded an avatar? Is it a string or boolean field?

Comment: Just updated, please have a look.

Comment: Ok, one more question, if user has an avatar, will we sort by it's value without considering created value?

Comment: The primary condition is to have an avatar. Users with an avatar are always before users without avatar. Then, these two "groups" (users with avatar and users without should be sorted by creation date).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an aggregation pipeline.

```
[
{$project: {
  _id: 1,
  created: 1,
  avatar: 1,
  avatarExists: {
    $cond: [
      {$ifNull: ["$avatar", false]},
      1,
      0
    ]
  }
}}, 
{$sort: {
  avatarExists: -1,
  created: 1
}}]
```

The $project stage adds a new field indicating if the avatar exists.  The $sort stage sorts first on if the avatar exists and then on the created date.

Comment: It works great! Thank you very much for the answer and the explanation!

Comment: Instead of $project, $addFields would be better like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f62U5mqR7AP)

Comment: This is practically how I did it, Lauren's answer was very helpful tho.

Answer (score 0):

in your sort you can define how they need to be sorted by... you just need to expand what you have.

`.sort({ created: 1, hasAvatar: -1 })`

Comment: I can't do it as I don't have `hasAvatar` field. I just updated question showing example collection I have.